# React Native Build Error With Yarn?

Tags: javascript, react-native, yarnpkg

Literally all I'm trying to do is move the initialization code from `index.android.js / index.ios.js` to and `app/index.js` file. I export that and import it back into `index.android.js` or `index.ios.js`.

Then I get the error.

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object`

Didn't have this issue when I used npm. Seems like yarn's build process might be different because whenever I save anything in my packager it says

`Bundling 'index.android.js'` but nothing about iOS.

My `app/index.js` looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Snapp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And my `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` files look like this

```
import Snapp from './app'
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Snapp', () => Snapp);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you restart the packager with `react native start -- --reset-cache` between yarn installs?

Comment: I ran `rm yarn.lock && rm -rf node_module && npm install` in my project and also ran `react-native start --reset-cache` and still getting the error.

Comment: Making sure the packager is down, also try `rm -rf ios/build ios/DerivedData rm -rf node_modules`. Open the Xcode project and clean (cmd + shift + K). Reinstall modules, restart packager with reset cache, and then run.

Comment: I'll try that too but also is there a way to Uninstall yarn? I've looked around but have seen anything.

Comment: Would refer to docs on how you installed it as well.

Comment: try ```rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build/ModuleCache/* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && yarn```

Comment: Don't use npm command. Use yarn install or react-native install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try registering the app in the same JS with the component.

> app/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  AppRegistry
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Snapp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Snapp', () => Snapp);
```

> index.ios.js / index.android.js

```
require('./app/');
```

Comment: Tried this but now it gives me a `Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly` error. When I reset back to the original code the error goes away.

Comment: @maxwel make sure you have '/' after app. require('./app/');

Comment: Still getting the error even changing it to `./app/`

Comment: @maxwellgover Are you running the packager? react-native start

Comment: @maxwellgover Great